# AWK adding if statement to add zero to number range 0 to 9 ( NEED TO USE AWK)

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, awk

Hi I need to format the date command output using awk and add zero before the days  starting 1 to 9 .

```
today=`date | awk {'print $1 " " $2  " " $3'}`
```

So in the above the output is

```
Wed Mar  2
```

I need to add 0 to 2   to get to days of the month 1 through 9

```
Wed  Mar 02
```

Ho can I add this command using the awk command

```
for i in 0{1..9}; do echo $i; done
```

So I need to add 0/zero to $3 when it's between 1 or 9

I tried doing it this way , but something is not working I get error

```
a3=`date|awk '{
if ($3 <=9)
       print $1" "$2" " "0"$3;
else
       print  $1" "$2" " $3;
}'`

echo $a3
```

Can you please assist?

Regards

Comment: look up `printf` in the `awk` man page

Comment: Please edit your code to tell us the specific behavior you are trying to get by not quoting your shell variable so we can help you get the same effect in a more robust way. Your question looks very much like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3):

If I were you I'd just specify a format directly:

```
$ date '+%a %b %d'
Wed Mar 02
```

[`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/date.html) takes a format string preceded by a `+` as its final argument.

Comment: I was 1 minute late :D

Comment: thx Tom - I know this command I need to do this  is an awk statement

Comment: I'm confused by this requirement. Could you edit your question to make it clearer what you're trying to do?

Comment: fair enough I update the question - I hope it makes more sens

Comment: You've shown *how* you are using `awk`, not why `awk` is necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you must do in `awk` you can use printf for formatted printing

```
$ echo 1 2 10 20 | awk -v RS=" " '{printf "%s\t-> %02d\n",$1,$1}'

1       -> 01
2       -> 02
10      -> 10
20      -> 20
```